# Download the file as custom name while open a file using window.open() in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, window.open

In react application, it display the file in new tab using `window.open(blobURL)`. Following is code snippet:

```
const fileURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(file);
window.open(fileURL);
```

The fileURL variable generated url like "blob:http://localhost:3010/9d8996ad-8c96-4d42-ba9c-80a79d0fcd91" and user try to save the file, it stores as the Guid name("9d8996ad-8c96-4d42-ba9c-80a79d0fcd91"). How can we download as "test.pdf".